# How to securely test malicious code injected in a website?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Recently a client's website got hacked and they injected a lot of malicious code (in over 256 files), I know how to decode the malicious code and examine what it does, but I'm wondering what if the client wants to see what the code did to his website and what type of information the hacker has? I'm not entirely sure how to setup a secure environment for testing purposes to show the client what happened and the type of information it showed.

A more compact/concise version of the question is:

- How to setup an environment to test PHP malicious code without risking anyone?
- What should I recommend the client to install to prevent such attacks?.

Personally, I've setup WordPress following hardening Wordpress, installed Wordfence and I've never had this issue, should I do the same for the client or are there other steps to further secure a Wordpress site?

Note: I know this is a 'common' question in StackOverflow though they all ask how to stop it or what it does, I'm more interested in knowing how to safely run it for demo purposes and if my current approach is enough to withhold (or make it harder to pull off) this type of attacks

Answer (score 0):

Safest bet would be to take a snapshot of your production database and copy all files in the production environment to a different server and load it to a testing environment that matches your production environment precisely but it not working with production data and is not accessible to the public. Also firewall it so that it can not access the internet in case the purpose of the malicious code is to send data to a remote user. Then run the code and check your server logs and any error messages that show up as well as performing a comparison of the testing site before and after the code was run and of the database image before and after the code was run.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel your website is effected by some vulnerability. Below you can find some useful tips to make your website safe.

- Change WordPress for admin (and all users with admin access).
- Change FTP and CPanel credentials to be safe for future.
- Replace **wp-admin** and **wp-includes** folders from latest fresh WordPress source code.
- Configure one of the security plugins for WordPress. For example :

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulletproof-security/

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/
- Once you have made website secure, install https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ and find which files are affected.
- You can remove those effected code manually and make it clean.
- If you are using free plugins from WordPress directory, just replace effected plugin to the new updated version.
- Follow same procedure for themes.
- Make sure to keep all plugins and themes updated to latest version.
- You must have to update WordPress version to latest version to minimize security risks.

**Note** :- There may be many other solutions, i have shared what i am following every time i face same situation.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @AndyLester, then why you haven't answered what OP asked for ?